# Will pthread_cancel cancel a thread while the thread is doing IO?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

The title is pretty self explanatory, cause when is the actual "cancelation point"?  POSIX requires that `read` is a cancelation point but is that when the thread first calls `read`, or once it's done?  When exactly does POSIX require the thread to be canceled?

Comment: Rich Felker (R.. here on SO) discusses exactly when a syscall is cancellable at https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cancellation point is at any time *during* the call to `read()`.  From [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_05_02):

> Cancellation points shall occur when a thread is executing the following functions: [....] `read()` [....]

So, to answer your titular question, yes.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, "man 7 pthreads" contains this:

> POSIX.1 specifies that certain functions must, and certain  other  functions  may,  be  cancellation
>          points.   If  a thread is cancelable, its cancelability type is deferred, and a cancellation request
>          is pending for the thread, then the thread is canceled when it calls a function that is a  cancella‐
>          tion point.

I read this to mean it is cancel-able when "read is called", not "during a read"...

However, if that is a concern for you and you don't want a specific thread to be cancelled in a critical section of code, you could call "pthread_setcancelstate() with "PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE" and after the critical section you could call it again, this time with "PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE".

Comment: Wrong inference — it is cancelable during a read.  The POSIX language is clearer than the Linux man pages here ([as in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27596133/132382)), but note that the Linux man page later says:  "[A]n implementation is likely to mark any non-standard function _that may block_ as cancellation point." (emphasis added)

Comment: @pilcrow: it's only cancelable if it still has not transfered data. See R..'s comments at https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12683